# How to display Advanced Custom Field Google Map on single product page woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I want to display a google map just under the short description part on my single product page using ACF Google Maps.

I have followed this tutorial in ACF: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

I have tested the solution by adding the php code to single-product.php:

```html
<?php 

$location = get_field('location');

if( !empty($location) ):
?>
<div class="acf-map">
 <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is displaying on the single product pages but not on the right place.

I would like to have the map somewhere in 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' location but I can figure out how to do that.

Is it possible to add it via a hook?

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your code to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook by using [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/). Also, note that you need to define the priority as WooCommerce adds many functions to that same hook, ([see source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L132-L147)) and the priority determines their order. I've guessed 30 would be appropriate as that should come after the excerpt.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'so_41625126_add_map', 30 );
function so_41625126_add_map() {

    if( function_exists( 'get_field' ) && $location = get_field( 'location' ) ) { ?>
        <div class="acf-map">
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: Tnaks Helga! Your answer was perfect! I got a nice ACF map on each product page!